# JS - Override localStorage to watch changes and get key/value

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'd like to override window.localStorage in order to get the key and the value and the stack trace. I've done this :

```
Object.defineProperty(window, 'localStorage', new (function() {

      this.get = async () => {
        console.log(this);
      };
    })());
```

but I don't figure out how I can get the key/value that have been set

Comment: You want to check what has been inserted into localStorage via `setItem()`?

Comment: Yeah but also with dot notation and bracket notation like storage.key and storage[key]

Comment: There is a 'storage' event on window, but from what I understood, it's fired for other webpages. So if you for example have your page open in two tabs, then inserting something into localStorage will cause an event in the second tab. It will not fire on the page that has made the change to localStorage. I also forgot to mention, that I have tried to override localStorage, but it throws error when I try to set an item "INVALID INVOCATION" or something like that

Comment: Hmm yeah I saw that, but I need to watch the active page :/

Comment: see my answer if that solution will work for you

Answer (score -1):

to get the value from the local storage:

```
let content = localStorage.getItem("INSERT_KEY")//you have to know the key to access the value
```

to override the local storage just remove the item:

```
localStorage.removeItem("SAME_KEY")
```

and re-set the value:

```
localStorage.setItem("SAME_KEY")
```

Comment: I don't want to override the value I want to override the method so I can watch for change events

Answer (score -1):

As I have mentioned in my comment, you cannot override localStorage, since it will cause an error when someone tries to use it.

There is a `storage` event, but it's only fired on another page in the same domain (for example when you have two tabs of the same page). It won't fire on the same page instance, which has changed something in local storage.

However, you can write a wrapper around localStorage.

For example:

```
function setItemWrapper(callback) {
  return (key, value) => {
    localStorage.setItem(key, value)
    callback(key, value)
  }
}

function onSetItem(key, value) {
  console.log(`Item set: ${key}=${value}`)
}

const setItem = setItemWrapper(onSetItem)

setItem('key', 'value')
console.log(localStorage.getItem('key'))
```

You can see a working example in this [CodePen](https://codepen.io/wilkoklak/pen/ZEWvbVQ)

Make sure to open the Console frame in the CodePen

Comment: Sorry but I'm using puppeteer and I want to watch when the localStorage is updated. I'm not setting item manually, i'm doing E2E testing